# SQL UPDATE with multiple WHERE (relations) conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I would like to know if it is possible to perform such UPDATE in oracle SQL database :

```
UPDATE mark
        SET
        mark=
        CASE
        WHEN mark.val<= 5 
            THEN val*1.1
        ELSE val END
        WHERE mark.id_classes = classes.id_classes 
            AND classes.ID_subject = subject.ID_subject
            AND subject.ID_subject = 5;
```

SQL developer returns error in this part :

```
WHERE mark.id_classes = classes.id_classes 
            AND classes.ID_subject = subject.ID_subject
            AND subject.ID_subject = 5;
```

So I guess that it is not possible to make such a complex condition, is it any other way to do that then?

Might be silly to try more `SELECT` like condition but on the other hand I don't see the reason why it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery:

```
UPDATE mark
    SET mark = val * 1.1
    WHERE mark.val <= 5 AND
          EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM classes c JOIN
                       subjects s
                       ON c.ID_subject = s.ID_subject
                  WHERE mark.id_classes = c.id_classes AND                       
                        s.ID_subject = 5
                 );
```

Notice that I moved the `CASE` condition to the `WHERE` clause so only the rows that need to be updated are updated.

Comment: Also works fine, even simpler in my opinion thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reference another two tables (`CLASSES` and `SUBJECT`) *just like that*, out of nowhere. Here's code which shows *how* you might have done that:

```
update mark m set
  m.mark = (select case when m.val <= 5 then m.val * 1.1
                        else m.val
                   end
            from classes c join subject s on c.id_subject = s.id_subject
            where c.id_classes = m.id_classes
              and s.id_subject = 5
           )
where ...
```

As you didn't use table aliases within `CASE`, I don't know which table the VAL column belongs to (so I presumed it is `MARK`).

Also, `UPDATE` itself might need the `WHERE` clause which would restrict number of rows to be updated.

Comment: Yeah, it works thank you for explaining also what was to problem.

Comment: This will set `mark` to `NULL` if there are no matching values.  I don't think that is what the OP intends.  It also unnecessarily updates rows.

Comment: Oh now I see what you meant, right should be updated with if EXIST or sth statement.

Comment: That's what the `...` behind `WHERE` means.

Answer (score 1):

I find that in cases like this a MERGE statement is easier to understand:

```
MERGE INTO MARK m
  USING (SELECT c.ID_CLASSES
           FROM CLASSES c
           WHERE c.ID_SUBJECT = 5) d
    ON (m.ID_CLASSES = d.ID_CLASSES)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET m.MARK = CASE
                          WHEN m.VAL <= 5 
                            THEN m.VAL * 1.1
                          ELSE
                             m.VAL
                        END
```

Or, since the ID_SUBJECT is a constant, you can simplify your update to

```
UPDATE MARK m
  SET m.MARK = CASE
                 WHEN m.VAL <= 5 
                   THEN m.VAL * 1.1
                 ELSE
                   m.VAL
                 END
  WHERE m.ID_CLASSES = 5
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Appreciate another approach :)